# Castle Windsor - Pass resolve arguments to the inferior layers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a web api project where controllers depend on some storage layer. E.g. 
each controller has similar code:

```
public class ResourceController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IResourceStorage _resourceStorage;
    private readonly IOtherStorage _otherStorage;


    public ResourceController(IResourceStorage resourceStorage, IOtherStorage otherStorage)
    {
       _resourceStorage = resourceStorage;
       _otherStorage = otherStorage;
    }

    // Web API Actions
}
```

A common code for storage looks like this:

```
public class ResourceStorage : DBProvider, IResourceStorage
{
    public ResourceStorage(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }

    // storage methods  
}
```

Based on some specific condition of the Web Api request, I need to be able to inject different connectionStrings to Storages of controller. Pseudo-code could look like that:

```
public class WindsorControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
   public IHttpController Create(
      HttpRequestMessage request,
      HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor,
      Type controllerType)
   {
      string connectionString = ChooseDbConnectionStringBasedOnRequestContext(request);

      var controller =
         (IHttpController)_container.Resolve(connectionString, controllerType, new {databaseType = connectionString});

      request.RegisterForDispose(
         new Release(
            () => _container.Release(controller)));

      return controller;
   }
}
```

I do not know how to pass the parameter to the storage in the less destructive way:)

What have I tried? Alternatives:

1. Pass parameterers as Castle Windsor *Additional Arguments* and treat it in next layer using *DynamicParameters*. The arguments get the controller layer but I could not find a way to get them to the storage - it has its own *CreationContext*, and I cannot find a way to pass it on from controller to storage.
2. Have N(equal to number of connection strings) containers and choose one of those inside *ControllerActivator*. Seems a huge and ugly solution, totally non-flexible but it works.
3. Create N sets of Controllers each with their own name and inside of storage *DynamicParameters* check Handler's component name and choose the connection string. From the *ControllerActivator* pass in the key to the correct set of Controllers. Also ugly - too many registrations of controllers and a lot of plumbing code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a factory pattern:

```
public interface IResourceStorageFactory
{
    IResourceStorage Create(int numberOfResources);
}

public class ResourceStorageFactory : IResourceStorageFactory
{
    public IResourceStorage Create(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var connectionString = ChooseDbConnectionStringBasedOnRequestContext(request);

        return new ResourceStorage(connectionString);
    }
}
```

and then simply

```
private readonly IResourceStorage _resourceStorage;
private readonly IOtherStorage _otherStorage;

public ResourceController(IResourceStorageFactory resourceStorageFactory, IOtherStorage otherStorage)
{
    _resourceStorage = resourceStorageFactory.Create(Request);
    _otherStorage = otherStorage;
}
```

Comment: It is much less intrusive, for sure. Thank you for the suggestion. Still there are 2 problems I see here: 1) One has to supply extra parametere StorageFactory to all the controllers (it can be made generic, but still one more parameter), 2) One has to call create before assigning every storage which also is kind of intrusive. I shall not mark your answer as accepted yet and hope someone has a more natural solution for it

Comment: For instance - could the factory be used on injected a certain type of IRegistration injection?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is introducing a connection string provider:

```
public interface IConnectionStringProvider
{
  string ConnectionString { get; }
}
```

When register this provider as per web request with a factory method:

```
 kernel.Register(
    Component.For(typeof (IConnectionStringProvider))
             .ImplementedBy(typeof (ConnectionStringProvider))
             .UsingFactoryMethod(
                (k, context) =>
                   new ConnectionStringProvider(context.AdditionalArguments["connectionString"].ToString()))
             .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

And inside the controller activator first resolve the connection string provider with the right parameters and then the controller:

```
 // The lifecycle of connection string provider if per web request.
 // We resolve it first time with the correct parameters,
 // so it is injected with the correct connection string throught the lifecycle of the request.
 _container.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>(new {connectionString});

 var controller =
    (IHttpController) _container.Resolve(controllerType);
```

It still not perfect and looks kind of hackish but it allows to keep dependencies on the interfaces of the inferior layer and requires less changes of the codebase from the solutions I've found